# only one AS items needed for language "plpgsql";

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run a `copy` command inside a `stored procedure`.
This copy command copies from `aws s3` to a table in `aws redshift`

This is the copy command

```
copy schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_temp
from
''''s3://root2/rawfiles/''''
iam_role ''''arn:aws:iam::743:role/redshift''''
csv DELIMITER ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 TRUNCATECOLUMNS;
```

I am trying to add it into a stored proc, which now looks like this.

here i am trying to create a `temp` table which contains all the data from `s3`, which is being copied to `temp` table using a `copy` command.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test() LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
'
BEGIN
drop table if exists 
schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_temp
;
create table 
schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_temp(emp_id int, emp_name varchar(100),hrly_rate int,mod_timestamp timestamp)
;

copy schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_temp
from
''''s3://root2/rawfiles/''''
iam_role ''''arn:aws:iam::743:role/redshift''''
csv DELIMITER ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 TRUNCATECOLUMNS;
drop table if exists 
schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_main
;

create table 
schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_main
as 
select h1.emp_id,h1.emp_name,h1.hrly_rate,h1.mod_timestamp
from schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_hstry h1
inner join (
select emp_id ,emp_name , max(mod_timestamp ) mod_timestamp
from schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_hstry
group by 1,2
) h2
on h1.emp_id=h2.emp_id
and h1.mod_timestamp=h2.mod_timestamp
group by 1,2,3,4
;

END;

'
```

But this throws the error :

```
only one AS items needed for language "plpgsql";
```

So , how to add a `copy` command inside a `stored procedure` or do i need to call the `copy` command separately ?

Answer (score 1):

[COPY is an allowed DML statement within a stored procedure.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html)

It looks like the error is referring to the AS keyword. As far as I know, the syntax in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html) requires the script after AS to be wrapped in `$$` and the `LANGUAGE plpgsql` designation should come after the script body . Example given in the documentation is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 a;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
/
```

so you should change the order of the script like follows (I cannot test this locally at this time)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test()
AS
$$
BEGIN
drop table if exists 
schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_temp
;
create table 
schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_temp(emp_id int, emp_name varchar(100),hrly_rate int,mod_timestamp timestamp)
;

copy schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_temp
from
''''s3://root2/rawfiles/''''
iam_role ''''arn:aws:iam::743:role/redshift''''
csv DELIMITER ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 TRUNCATECOLUMNS;
drop table if exists 
schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_main
;

create table 
schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_main
as 
select h1.emp_id,h1.emp_name,h1.hrly_rate,h1.mod_timestamp
from schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_hstry h1
inner join (
select emp_id ,emp_name , max(mod_timestamp ) mod_timestamp
from schema1_ghsheet.ghseet_hstry
group by 1,2
) h2
on h1.emp_id=h2.emp_id
and h1.mod_timestamp=h2.mod_timestamp
group by 1,2,3,4
;

END;

$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```